# transform:rotate(-90deg) creates unwanted space

Tags: css, css-transforms

I am using `transform` property of CSS3. It creates space on the left side of the div after it rotates it. Heres my [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/godtcfkm/)

SO want some code:

```
<div>
   Maglevboard
</div>

<style>
   div {
     font-size:5em;
     transform:rotate(-90deg);
     display:inline-block;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: That's because how `rotate` works - it rotates from the element's center. Not sure whether it can be circumvented

Answer (score 3):

You can fix it by adding a translation and using a proper `transform-origin`. I think you want

```css
div {
  font-size: 5em;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>Maglevboard</div>
```